# Is "get work turn around" a sarcasm in comment from client?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sarcasm

Got a client's comment and we ended our contract. She told me she'd write a good review. Here's what I've got:

> I appreciated your English language skills. It meant that we could take advantage of your timezone in getting work turned around. All the best in your next gig.

Is that a sarcasm saying implicitly about I didn't do my work well?

Comment: *Getting work turned around* simply means *getting the job done.*  The phrase **does not** imply *moving backwards*.  There appears to be no sarcasm in your client's comment, just an honest, brief but good review.

Comment: Yes, if a job is turned around it is completed in a timely fashion.

Comment: Thanks @EllieK-Don'tsupporther Coz this phrase has two opposite meanings, it confuses me. Now it feels clear to me.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! @MichaelHarvey

Comment: As both answers and many comments say, your client was complimenting you. In this context, “turn around“ means not just get the job done, but also - I am assuming that you are in India and the client is in North America or Europe or something similar - the client would send you email asking for a feature or a fix in her afternoon, you would complete it during your day, and  it might will be working for her the next morning. “Turning around stuff overnight“ from her point of view.

Comment: @KrazyGlew Yes! That was the work pattern between us, which was almost the same as your assumption. I live in Asia, and English is my second language. It's just...mentioning "English skills" first, then saying a phrase with 2 opposite meanings, sounds like a mother tongue speaker takes advantage of English-using and uses an ambiguous phrase in final review on purpose. Do you get what I mean? That's why I posted a question to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, she's not being sarcastic. She's using a perfectly normal meaning of "turn around" (from [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/turn-around)):

> TRANSITIVE to complete a piece of work, process, or activity within a particular time
> *We can produce quality work and turn it around very quickly.*

When she says that you got "work turned around", she means that you completed it within a particular time.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is clear to me! And thank you for using Markdown to help me with the question editing!

Answer (score 3):

She's probably using the phrase "turned around" in reference to the common term **[turnaround](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turnaround)**. Scroll past the first definition to look at the others:

> an occasion when a business, plan, or system suddenly becomes successful

> any change from one thing to its opposite

> the amount of time that it takes for a piece of work to be done, a product to be supplied, etc

> a big change that turns a bad situation into a good one

And so on. I think it's clear she wasn't being sarcastic, and implied that you were a very big help to her business.